# Support Library 22.1 material interpolators for Fragment transition animations

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm attempting to use the `fast_out_linear_in` interpolator for a Fragment transition animation.  The support library now provides this interpolator via its [FastOutLinearIn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/animation/FastOutLinearInInterpolator.html?utm_campaign=ASL221-415&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) class.

The way to specify fragment transition animations is via FragmentTransaction's [setCustomAnimations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method which only takes animation XML resource IDs.

This is a problem because the support library interpolators aren't available via XML, e.g. this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Will still get the error `@android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in requires API level 21` when support-v4:22.1.1 is a dependency.

Is there a workaround available for using custom animation classes for Fragment transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the FragmentManager the only way to give it a custom made animation is through overloading the `Fragment.onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)`

From the source code; android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager

```
Animation loadAnimation(Fragment fragment, int transit, boolean enter,
        int transitionStyle) {
    Animation animObj = fragment.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter,
            fragment.mNextAnim);
    if (animObj != null) {
        return animObj;
    }

    if (fragment.mNextAnim != 0) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mHost.getContext(), fragment.mNextAnim);
        if (anim != null) {
            return anim;
        }
    }
...
}
```